# AWS : Exporting logs from Amazon CloudWatch to Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to export the logs generated for a Lambda function invocation (or all events) to Amazon Redshift. I am not sure how to do this. I can access the logs locally but I want to perform this process on the AWS Cloud. I am not sure whether this is possible but any help regarding this use case would be great. I am new to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subscription filter to stream the logs to another service. YOu can't directly choose Redshift, but you can specify something like Kinesis or Lambda which can then send the data on to redshift.

See this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jack, it helped me go in the right direction.

Comment: Was the subscription filter ultimately what you needed?